# How to return PHP variables on success AJAX/jQuery POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How do I use AJAX to return a variable in PHP? I am currently using echo in my controller to display a price on `dropdown .change` in a `div` called price.

However I have a hidden field which I need to return the row id to on change. How do I assign the return var in jQuery so that I can echo it in my hidden field?

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pricingEngine').change(function() {
         var query = $("#pricingEngine").serialize();
         $('#price').fadeOut(500).addClass('ajax-loading');
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "store/PricingEngine",
             data: query,
             success: function(data)
             {
                  $('#price').removeClass('ajax-loading').html('$' + data).fadeIn(500);
             }
         });
    return false;
   });

});
```

## Controller

```
function PricingEngine()
{
    //print_r($_POST);
    $this->load->model('M_Pricing');
    $post_options = array(
      'X_SIZE' => $this->input->post('X_SIZE'),
      'X_PAPER' => $this->input->post('X_PAPER'),
      'X_COLOR' => $this->input->post('X_COLOR'),
      'X_QTY' => $this->input->post('X_QTY'),
      'O_RC' => $this->input->post('O_RC')
                          );

    $data = $this->M_Pricing->ajax_price_engine($post_options);

    foreach($data as $pData) {
        echo number_format($pData->F_PRICE / 1000,2);
        return $ProductById = $pData->businesscards_id;
    }
}
```

## View

Here is my hidden field I want to pass the VAR to every-time the form is changed.
" />

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well.. One option would be to return a JSON object. To create a JSON object in PHP, you start with an array of values and you execute `json_encode($arr)`. This will return a JSON string.

```
$arr = array(
  'stack'=>'overflow',
  'key'=>'value'
);
echo json_encode($arr);

{"stack":"overflow","key":"value"}
```

Now in your jQuery, you'll have to tell your `$.ajax` call that you are expecting some JSON return values, so you specify another parameter - `dataType : 'json'`. Now your returned values in the `success` function will be a normal JavaScript object.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "...",
  data: query,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data.stack); // overflow
    console.log(data.key);   // value
  }
});
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion. It seems to be working but having some issues.. Please see new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213361/getting-undefined-response-from-jquery-ajax-form-post   Thanks! ;)

Comment: how to get this string into php variable?

Comment: @151291 - In my example, the data inside the `query` variable will arrive inside the `$_POST` variable when this code executes the `AJAX` request.

Comment: @151291 - it's really not clear what you are asking.. Please open a new post (if you can't find an answer on an already existing question).

Comment: @151291 - without seeing the code you are using it's quite difficult to make suggestions. This is why I suggested opening a new post to solve your problem.

Comment: ok ok i got answer ... json elements having numeric index 0 like this `["0":{"id":"1001","full_name":"raju "}]` , all elements in 0th index. i got it while writing `document.write(result)` without write `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: what is the advantage of using `console.log` and how can i access this json data into php script, I tried `$_POST['stack']` but not able to access, plus i tried `var_dump($_POST['stack'])` shows undefined index.

Comment: controller returns json encoded object, how can i get this object into php script?, it means how can i pass an json object from ajax success function into php script

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode($RESPONDE);
exit();
```

The exit is not to display other things except answer. RESPONDE is good to be array or object.
You can access it at

```
success: function(data)
             { data }
```

data is the responde array or whatever you echo..
For example...

```
echo json_encode(array('some_key'=>'yesss')); exit();
```

at jquery

```
success: function(data){ alert(data.some_key); }
```

Comment: controller returns json encoded object, how can i get this object into php script?, it means how can i pass an json object from ajax success function into php script

Comment: @151291 to start any PHP action you have to make new request so you have to make again ajax.. But its not logical 1 ajax to trigger 2nd ajax to the same script, its better to put your logic in the 1st script which you trigger with ajax request, and there to run the 2nd logic which you want to add. (If its possible of course.. else you have to make a new ajax request)

Comment: json.decode() is not PHP function. Please go to PHP.net and search for JSON handling the documentation is full and you will understand it. I am not teacher.

Comment: Ya its my mistake, not `json.decode` its `json_decode()`, so this is php function right?

Comment: from your answer, how can i get `data` values into php script if it is object.

Answer (score 1):

if u are returning only single value from php respone to ajax then u can set it hidden feild using val method

```
$("#hidden_fld").val(return_val);
```