# Getting undefined response from jQuery AJAX form post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pricingEngine').change(function() {
         var query = $("#pricingEngine").serialize();
         $('#price').fadeOut(500).addClass('ajax-loading');
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "index.php/welcome/PricingEngine",
             data: query,
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {
               $('#price').removeClass('ajax-loading').html('$' + data.F_PRICE).fadeIn(500);
               $('#sku').attr('value') = (data.businesscards_id);
             }
         });
    return false;
   });
});
```

Need to set #sku as value of a hidden form field (not sure if i am doing that correctly in the above jQuery code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sku" id="sku" value="*/PUT VAR VALUE HERE/*" />
```

Also need to pass the `F_PRICE` to the `#price div`.

Console in Chrome shows the JSON response as:

```
[
 {
  "businesscards_id":"12",
  "X_SIZE":"1.75x3",
  "X_PAPER":"14ptGlossCoatedCoverwithUV(C2S)",
  "X_COLOR":"1002",
  "X_QTY":"250",
  "O_RC":"NO",
  "F_PRICE":"12490",
  "UPS_GROUND":"12000",
  "UPS_TWODAY":"24000",
  "UPS_OVERNIGHT":"36000"
 }
]
```

Yet I only get 'undefined' in the price box. What is the reason here?

Comment: just use `shift()` in ajax response/success method, n code will be worked fine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure returned as JSON is an array `[]` containing one element which is the object `{}` you are targeting. Access it via its array index `[0]`

```
// Access the array-wrapped object via its [0] index:
$('#price').removeClass('ajax-loading').html('$' + data[0].F_PRICE).fadeIn(500);
// Likewise here, and set the value with .val()
$('#sku').val(data[0].businesscards_id);
```

You could also `.shift()` the first element off the array and use that as you have it:

```
// Pull the first element off the array, into the same variable
// WARNING: Use a different variable if the array has multiple elements you need to loop over later.
// You *don't* want to do it this way if the array contains multiple objects.
data = data.shift();
$('#price').removeClass('ajax-loading').html('$' + data.F_PRICE).fadeIn(500);
$('#sku').val(data.businesscards_id);
```

Comment: Yeah just realized the data = data[0];  But why do I need it there?

Comment: @fabio What do you mean why do you need it there? Your AJAX call returns an array. If you want it to return only the single object, you would need to modify it on the server side.

Comment: Ok I see why I have to do that now .. I wasn't aware of the JSON format. Code is partially working however. `$('#sku').val(data[0].businesscards_id);` does not set the value of the hidden field input.. Any ideas? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @fabio What is it setting the value to? `.val()` has been in jQuery since 1.0. Are you using a super old version?

Comment: no latest version google cdn -- its not setting anything and no console errors either:  Here it is from source `<input type="hidden" name="sku" id="sku" value="" />`

Comment: Oh oh, don't look at the source. The page source won't change! Use the Chrome console to inspect the element, and there you will see the updated value.  The page source is always the static source as sent by the server. It doesn't reflect updates.

Comment: Ok you're correct thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that. It is reflected correctly in console. Since I am returning this data from the database the JSON response is showing my table col names. For security issues I do not what that to happen. I will ask a new question on this topic. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: see new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213570/how-do-obfuscate-json-response-when-dealing-with-a-db-query   Thanks again!

Comment: Was actually just looking at it - it popped up next in the PHP list when I went back to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

This the the proper way (best)

```
$('#sku').val(data.businesscards_id);
```

If you insist on using attr, this should work

```
$('#sku').attr('value', data.businesscards_id);
```