# How do obfuscate JSON response when dealing with a DB query?

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

```
[
 {
  "businesscards_id":"12",
  "X_SIZE":"1.75x3",
  "X_PAPER":"14ptGlossCoatedCoverwithUV(C2S)",
  "X_COLOR":"1002",
  "X_QTY":"250",
  "O_RC":"NO",
  "F_PRICE":"12490",
  "UPS_GROUND":"12000",
  "UPS_TWODAY":"24000",
  "UPS_OVERNIGHT":"36000"
 }
]
```

This JSON encode response is seen in console of Chrome. This array is being returned from a DB query. It is showing my table column names. For security reasons I do not want to show my table column names. **How can this JSON object be obfuscated or hashed and/or encoded or dynamically re-written to keep my table col names private?**

Comment: If your security depends on your field names being secret, then your security, frankly, sucks. Do you think a bank would worry about using the obvious "account_number" moniker to store your... account number in their client/user tabls?

Comment: I would just suggest - if you don't want your column names known, then just don't send them down.  If you are using a generic fetch loop that pairs column names and values, you would need to change it such that you are manually setting the property name with its value.

Comment: was changing the field names in the JSON really that difficult to figure out?

Comment: If it _really_ mattered, you could forego the object literal entirely in the JSON and just send back a plain array of values on the assumption that they always occur in the same order and can be accessed by numeric index.  That's more confusing and more work though. This is nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you wish to use the record once it has been received.  One strategy might be to return an array of the values only, discarding the keys. Then in your code, use your private knowledge of which array value you need when you process the record.  Something like:

```
var result=[];
Object.keys(record).forEach(function(key){result.push(record[key]);});
```

And then in your code, use array indices to access the values.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do anything to your JSON.

If you don't want your column names to be visible, just dont use your column names. Create a new array using new keys to send with JSON and then change that array back into one containing your column names afterwards.

But it really shouldn't be a problem people seeing them. Nobody has access to your database so letting people see column names isn't an issue.

Comment: If somebody is able to do SQL injection, they can just do `SHOW COLUMNS` to get all your columns.

Answer (score 1):

SQL statement:

```
SELECT `col_name` AS 'something_else'
```

But also, as everyone else said, don't do this for security. It is pointless.