# Ajax response conflicting css

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am displaying two functions in Modal head and Modal body using ajax.
Before sending ajax request the modal looks like this

[image]

After ajax response the modal looks like this

[image]

Where is the issue?

Cart.php

```
include('includes/Cart_code.php');

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
        $cart_class = new cart_class($_POST['ID']);
        $cart_class->cart_head_info_print();
        $cart_class->cart_body_info_print();
        exit();
       }
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Cart.php",
                data: {"ID":id},
                success: function(result){
                    $('#ajaxResult').html(result);

                }
            });
        });
</script>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
          <img src="" class="showPic">
            <div id="ajaxResult">
            <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">

              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
              <!---HERE HEADER DATA WILL BE DISPLAY---->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                <!---HERE BODY DATA WILL BE DISPLAY---->
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please the take product name from ***ajax response*** and append to the header part like below,

```
success:function(data){

   if(!data){$('#ajaxResult .modal-header').append(data);}    

}
```

as the same append into corresponding div for description and all.

REF: [How to return PHP variables on success AJAX/jQuery POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212882/how-to-return-php-variables-on-success-ajax-jquery-post)

Hope you will found the answer here.!!

Comment: And for the body i will write same like if(!data){$('#ajaxResult .modal-body').append(data);}

Comment: From ajax response, i am receiving ID of product to which  against i am calling two functions in my header and body, Now how will i split them into their corresponding portions?

Comment: if you are getting prodcut id means,split it first.after the apply into it.

Comment: What is the method to split them ?

Comment: example: var pn=data.productid;append to header($(selector for header).append(pn);) and then var pd=data.description.append to body($(selector for body).append(pd);)

Comment: which type of data format you getting?json or else?

Comment: I am trying to follow your logic. In my case, i am receiving ID, so should i split it like this?
 var pn=data.ID;append to header($(selector for header).append(pn);)?

Comment: if your data coming json object data format.you may split like this

Comment: refer this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: return the values in different variable in php and get the result via ajax from php function 1) $cart_class->cart_head_info_print();
       2) $cart_class->cart_body_info_print();

Comment: use those variable which will be coming via ajax.

Comment: And append into body and header selectors..thats simple

Comment: mean to say that i should grab the ID coming from ajax in two seperate php variables?
Is that you are saying ?

Comment: after grab value in two separate variables, next how would i update ajax and html part?

Comment: please refer it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212882/how-to-return-php-variables-on-success-ajax-jquery-post

Comment: Sample of your requirement.Use this one.

Comment: Hey!
my header and body displaying contents based on same ID. By splitting same ID into two php variables and further working based on your suggested solution would be feasible?

Comment: And yes, i am getting ID in the form of variable like $id. Now how to split it into two different variables?